# "Look at" vs "Look on"

Tags: phrase-usage

I just got asked which sounds better, and I have no idea which one should be preferred:

> "A closer look on how buildings are manufactured."

vs.

> "A closer look at how buildings are manufactured."

Is there a difference, or personal preference, or which one should it be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**: Thanks to FumbleFingers' ear, StoneyB's mind and Snailboat's eye I will "modify" my answer. Many thanks to all.

Only **look at** can be the acceptable choice in this instance. **To look on** is a verb, but in the sentence below it is used as a noun.

> "**a** closer **look at** how buildings etc."

(Original answer)

I think it's the word, closer, which forces me to prefer "at". We often use **look at** to mean to see something with attention, whereas **look on** can sometimes mean to consider, take into consideration.

Comment: Concur. To 'look on' is either to stand by (idly) and watch something, or to have an opinion about something (*to look on X as Y*); to 'look at' something is to give it careful attention.

Comment: I don't think I can concur. With or without the word "closer", *a look **on how** [something is done]* doesn't sound remotely acceptable to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers On further review, I agree - I was amplifying Mari-Lou A's final sentence and thinking of the verbs, not OP's nouns.

Comment: It's been here long enough without modification. I'll post an answer.

Comment: I'll illustrate my convoluted thinking, please tell me if I'm mistaken. I can **look on the bright side**, which means take into consideration that life's not all that bad. So, if "I *look on how* buildings are manufactured", I am considering, *reflecting on* how they are built. It's the word "closer", preceding the verb, "look", which means to pay *careful attention* that swayed me to prefer the preposition: at in my answer.

Comment: You can *look on the bright side*, but in that case *look* is a verb.  This is the noun, *a look*, and you can't have **a look on*, only *a look at*.

Comment: @snailboat of course you're right! I hadn't registered the difference. I will make amends.

Comment: @snailboat: You can use a *lot* of different prepositions after "look" in different contexts, but here we're specifically talking about *look xxx **how***. I can (just about) contrive an example such as *"I look on how my son eats with his mouth open as totally unacceptable"*, but I don't think that would help OP.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou: I'll let my answer stand because it can't do any harm (and may be useful to some), but I wouldn't have posted it at all if you'd made that edit earlier, and I'm quite happy to upvote yours now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Again, that's the verb, not the noun, so I don't think your example is particularly relevant.  In this context, we're discussing a phrase containing the noun.

Comment: @snailboat: You can certainly have *a look on/in/around/over/under/etc. [something]* (in order to find something else that might be there). It's not obvious to me the verb/noun distinction makes much difference in terms of what prepositions are credible, but it *is* obvious to me your options are much more limited if the next word is **how**.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was that only **at** is valid in OP's construction (which is a noun phrase, not a sentence).

But it's worth noting that in an *actual* sentence, it's just about possible to use a different preposition between **look** and **how**...

> When as a therapist you see a client, instead of *looking **at** how* he or she fits the existing research, you should [*look **for** how*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kRMF-TBU7ecC&pg=PA66&dq=%22look%20for%20how%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_ku2UYr7K8Gh0QWs7YGgDg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22look%20for%20how%22&f=false) the client disobeys the rules of research.

The reason that writer specifically uses *for* in the second instance is that it strongly implies *focussed attention* attempting to detect a *specific thing*. Looking *at* something can often mean little more than "allowing your gaze to rest on something, with no clear purpose or special concentration".

As @StoneyB comments, *to look **on*** is normally only used to mean either *to stand by (idly) and watch something*, or *to have an opinion about something (to look on X as Y)*. Neither of which apply here.

Answer (score 0):

You **look at** something for more details of it; you **look on** something to see what is going to happen with it, and may overlook its details.
After **looking at** it, you decided to **look on** for a while.